# What is the implication of having the internal energy equal the Gibbs free energy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I came up with a hypothetical equation of state, where one of the consequences is that $U=G$, where $U$ is the internal energy and $G$ is the Gibbs free energy. I wanted to ask the chemists, is there a fundamental problem with this? Are there any real systems where this could happen? Thank you for your time

Comment: I am curious about your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G=U+p \cdot V-T \cdot S$ by its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) and is also often called free enthalpy, as $G = H - T \cdot S$ and $H = U + p \cdot V$, where $H$ is [enthalpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy). So if $G=U$, then $S=p \cdot V/T$.

$pV/T$ is about constant at usual conditions for real gases, or even exactly constant for ideal gases ( $pV/T=nR$ ). It decreases with $T$ for condensed phases at constant pressure, or can dramatically grow with $T$ for condensed phases at constant volume.

[Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) $S$ increases with $T$ via $\mathrm{d}S=đQ/T=C(T) \cdot \mathrm{d}T/T$.

So $G=U$ could be true just accidentally for particular conditions, where both functions $S=f(T,p)$ and $pV/T = g(T,p)$ cross each other.

$G=U$ has no special meaning, but that the non free part of energy $T \cdot S$, blocked for work usage by [the second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics), is accidentally equal to the $pV$ term.

$G=H$, or $A=U$  would be a different case, as it would mean a system must have zero entropy, what is not possible for $T \gt 0$.

( $A=U-TS$ is the [Helmholtz (free) energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy)  )

Comment: Thank you! Can you reference any books that specifically state this somewhere?

Comment: Any textbooks with foundations of thermodynamics. See e.g. [CH  SE : resources for learning chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry). It may not be stated explicitly like the above, but is is the direct consequence of what is there. BTW, you did quite a poor job in a priori research before asking the question.

Comment: sorry, man. I'm just a lowly CS major.

Comment: NP.  Even humble CS majors are able to search for definitions of the basic TD quantities, if they operate with them.

Comment: I did know about the definitions you listed, however, the rest of the stuff you wrote wasn't immediately obvious to me. Sorry if I fucked up

Comment: No, it is OK, every wise person  is learning the whole life.

Comment: by the way, I'm guessing the quantity TS doesn't really have a name, or does it? I know that -PV is the Landau free energy for homogenous systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117375/discussion-between-poutnik-and-daniel-gusmao).